# Internet Explorer showing PPT

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, internet-explorer-11, libreoffice-impress

How to make IE11 to show PPT files in browser? I've configured IE to run ActiveX, and installed ActiveX component as suggested [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/ActiveX_Control_to_Display_Documents_in_Internet_Explorer), however still no luck.

Comment: Are you sure this plugin covers PPT files? It might be limited to Open Document files, which would mean you can only view ODP presentations, not PPT.

Comment: Well there was this option when installing ActiveX component as described: [link](https://i.imgur.com/kAgo2eV.png)

Comment: This setting has nothing to do with IE or the ActiveX plugin, it covers only double-clicking a file from the File Explorer.

Comment: That image looks like it's the installer for LibreOffice, which allows you to open PPT files inside the software package.  But that doesn't mean it'll also let you open PPT files inside IE.   You would need to convert it to a LibreOffice format.

Comment: Are you sure it has nothing to do with ActiveX? Because that's how the component is [called](https://i.imgur.com/lPnBInX.png)

Comment: Yes.  The image you just linked is the installation screen for the full application installation for LibreOffice.  Not the installation for the ActiveX control.  Installing the ActiveX control won't let you open PPT files in IE.  See previous comments.

Comment: It is for installing ActiveX component. The image is for exactly that.

Comment: No, it isn't.  The window you linked is the FULL application installer.  Installing the ActiveX is a separate option, as shown in the window - ie it's part of the full installation package.  Also, the text to the right of the option shows that this feature has also been deprecated by LibreOffice developers.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to save a PowerPoint presentation as a web page was deprecated in Office 2010, so it's no longer possible to do this.  And the link you provided is for LibreOffice files, when you asked about PPT (Microsoft PowerPoint).  Can you provide some context around the reason you want to do this? We may be able to help you come up with an alternate solution.

LibreOffice did allow display (feature has been deprecated) of their presentations in IE using the ActiveX control, but you would need to convert the presentation to LibreOffice format.